# How to count number of rows using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I try to count number of rows using JPA.I want to use where clause 
however I can't.

```
CriteriaBuilder qb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
cq.select(qb.count(cq.from(MyEntity.class)));
cq.where();  //how to write where clause 
return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

How can I set where clause forexample where age="45".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ergul have a look [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria)

Comment: And what does the documentation of your chosen JPA implementation say about how to do the WHERE clause of Criteria? You don't say why you "can't", or what you have tried

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`ParameterExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/ParameterExpression.html). Note: *Untested*.

```
CriteriaBuilder qb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
cq.select(qb.count(cq.from(MyEntity.class)));
ParameterExpression<Integer> p = qb.parameter(Integer.class);
q.where(qb.eq(c.get("age"), 45));
return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

[Reference](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/where).

Comment: Yes, it should as your are running `CriteriaQuery` `cq`. I just took your sample source code and added `ParameterExpression`.

Answer (score 20):

The best and simple way in jpa :

```
public interface YourEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<YourEntity, Serializable> {

Long countByAgeGreaterThan(Integer age);

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
EntityManagerFactory emf =
                    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("your table name");
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


            // JPA Query Language is executed on your entities (Java Classess), not on your database tables;

            Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM your Classname WHERE ... etc");
            long count = (long) query.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `EntityManager.createQuery()` instead of the CriteriaBuilder it looks like this:

```java
final TypedQuery<Number> query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(e) FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.age = :age", Number.class);
query.setParameter("age",45);
final long count = query.getSingleResult().longValue();
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use the Query parameter,
Example :

```
StringBuilder strQuery ;
    strQuery= new StringBuilder();
    try {
        strQuery.append("FROM SSS s where s.age:age");
        Query query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(
                strQuery.toString());
        query.setParameter("age", 45);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info("Erreur", e);
    }
```

it's useful for you?