# Get the number of rows in my table as an Integer

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, count

I want to create a method to return the number of rows in my table called "album", in an integer.

```
private static int getnbofalbum() {
        int nbofalbum;
        String jpql = "select count(*) from Album";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
        nbofalbum = query.getSingleResult();
        System.out.println("nbofalbum :" + nbofalbum);
        return nbofalbum;
    }
```

this is what I would in a way have, but `query.getSingleResult()` gives back an object, even if my query should give back a number, what can I do to get the number of rows in a simple way ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count number of rows using JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211806/how-to-count-number-of-rows-using-jpa)

Comment: It's return `Long` wrapper class of long. Do like `long nbofalbum = (long)query.getSingleResult();`

Comment: Allright I changed to "long nbofalbum = (long)query.getSingleResult();", and it works just fine, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should declare nbofalbum as Long, cause count(*) return a Long , and u cant just cast Long into int